# I wrote a c++ code to strip out the spaces of a sentence but when i try to print it it won't print past the first word

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
# include <iostream>
# include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int stripWhite(char *str);

int main ()
{

 char str[50];
 cout << "Enter a sentence . " << endl;
 cin >>str;
 cout << "Your sentence without spaces is : " << endl;
 cout << (str) << endl; // This is my problem. The sentence only prints the first word

 stripWhite(str);
 cout << "There were " << stripWhite(str) << " spaces." << endl;
 return 0;
}
int stripWhite(char *str)
{
 char *p = str;
 int count = 0;
 while (*p)
 {
  if (*p != ' ')
   count++;
  {
   *p++;
  }
 }
 return count;
```

Comment: If you use the *format as code* option in the edtor, your post will be much more readable

Comment: nitpick: you wrote a **C** job with C++ display debug thrown in.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin` treats spaces as end of string indicators.

In order to get the full sentence use `std::getline`. since this expects a std::string as one of its parameters, you will have to adjust your stripWhite-function accordingly:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

int stripWhite(string str); //change the formal parameter's type

int main ()
{

 string str;
 cout << "Enter a sentence . " << endl;
 getline(cin, str,'\n'); //use getline to read everything that has been entered till the press of enter
 cout << "Your sentence without spaces is : " << endl;
 cout << (str) << endl; // This is my problem. The sentence only prints the first word

 stripWhite(str);
 cout << "There were " << stripWhite(str) << " spaces." << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

int stripWhite(string str)
{

 int count = 0;
 char* p = str.c_str;
 while (*p)
 {
  if (*p != ' ')
   count++;
  {
   *p++;
  }
 }
 return count;
}
```

Comment: Your `stripWhite` method is not doing anything here, as `p` is not initialized and you never modify `str` which is passed by value anyway....

Comment: @Mtthieu: thanls for the hint, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to replace your function with the C++ string type, you can use cin.getline to get a c string (char array)

```
cin.getline(str, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, you should use `std::getline` instead of `cin >> str`.

However, there are multiple other problems in the code  you provided.

- Why use char array when you could use `std::string` ? Why are you so sure that 50 characters will be enough ?
- Your `stripWhite` function doesn't seem to strip anything : you count the number of non-space characters, but you are not actually removing anything. Note that if you switch to `std::string` instead of plain of char arrays, you could use a standard algorithm to do the job (on the top of my head, I guess [`std::remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) would be appropriate)
- Assuming that `stripWhite` *did* actually modify the input string, why would you want to call it twice from your main ? If the goal is to strip the string in the first place, and *then* print the number of removed space, make `stripWhite` return the number of removed spaces and store this result in the main.

For example :

```
const int nbSpacesStripped = stripWhite(str);
cout << "There were " << nbSpacesStripped << "spaces." << endl;
```

Comment: actually, the erase/remove idiom here (which is awkward) because a simple value (' ') is sufficient, there is no need for a predicate.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Absolutely right, `std::remove` is just as good, I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: I do prefer `boost::erase_all(str, ' ');` by the way, so much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Behold [Boost String Algorithms](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) and more particularly the [replace/erase](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1701549) routines.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

size_t stripWhiteSpaces(std::string& str)
{
  size_t const originalSize = str.size();
  boost::erase_all(str, ' ');
  return originalSize - str.size();
}

int main ()
{

  std::string str;
  std::cout << "Enter a sentence . \n";
  getline(std::cin, str);

  size_t const removed = stripWhiteSpaces(str);
  std::cout << "Your sentence without spaces is :\n";
  std::cout << (str) << '\n';

  std::cout << "There were " << removed << " spaces.\n";
  system("pause");
}
```